# Powershell Script run multiple times on Friday

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a script which needs to run once a day, except on Friday when it needs to run 3 times. Once for Saturday, Sunday and Monday. Normally it generates a report for the next day. Here's what it looks like:

```
$Tomorrow = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$PlaylistDate = $Tomorrow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
### Rest of script based off of $Tomorrow ###
```

On Friday though, I want it to run for the next 3 days all at the same time. What is the most efficient way to get that done? I know I could copy and paste the entire script 3 times for use on Friday, but it seems there has to be a more efficient way.

Thanks in advance for your help! I'm very much a beginner and this site has been invaluable to me.

Comment: you can create a for or while loop and put the code within. set the loop counter to 3 for friday alone. inside the loop add the counter to the day so that   sat,sun,mon are run and reset it to 0 once done.

Comment: So did you schedule the script **not** to run on sat,sun? Put the rest of the script in a function and check for friday `if (( get-date ).DayOfWeek.value__ -eq 5){...}`

Comment: And you're not using the Task Scheduler because...?

Comment: I should've clarified in the question, I'll use the task scheduler to schedule it to run M-F. For Friday though I want it to run 3 times. I think @LotPings broke the mental log jam. Thank you guys!